# Delegating to the correct method of the same name

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, delegates, protocols

I have three classes **Class A**, **Class B**, **Class C**.

**Class A** declares a protocol as follows

```
@protocol calculate <NSObject>

@required
-(void)addNumbers;
-(void)calculateTotal;

@end
```

In the implementation for **Class A** i have a defined a property as such.

```
static id <calculate> delegate;
```

]
**Class B** and **Class C** have the implemented the protocol and methods the defined in them.

In the implementation file for Class A, if i want to call the correct protocol methods implemented by Class B and Class C i am doing the following

```
 id <calculate> delegate = [Class B alloc] init];
 [delegate addNumbers];

 id <calculate> delgate = [Class C alloc] init];
 [delegate addNumbers];
```

Even though this works i have a feeling this is not right. I want to know if its possible for a single delegate object to determine and call the correct **addNumbers** on Class B or Class C

Comment: I've never seen a static delegate.

Comment: For Class C, you meant `[anotherDelegate addNumbers];`? Is it a copy-and-paste mistake, or?

Comment: btw: you are calling the delegate and anotherDelegate properties. but they are not.

Comment: Since objective c is a "dynamic" typed language so I think you just assign the object (Class B or Class C object) to delegate and run-time would automatically call the  method by looking at the object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest putting the protocol into its own file. Class A then imports that file and declares support for it "@interface Class_A : NSObject  (also, please capitalize the "C").

Normally, the delegate would be a pre-existing object. It makes no sense to create it for the new object, as the whole idea of a protocol is to be able to message an existing object without having to know all about it.

So when you create B and C, you set their delegate property (using __weak) to some exiting object, one that meets the protocol. Those new objects can then message that object.

So suppose you are making a calculator, and you want one delegate to handle calculations. Fine - in say the UIViewController, create this object that can do that, and keep a strong reference to it. As you then create buttons that need a delegate to do calculations, you set their delegate property with this object you created earlier

Answer (score 0):

Why are you allocating Class B and C in Class A.

In class A it should call the delegate methods `[self.delegate addNumbers]`
and shouldn't need a reference to the class that is implementing it.

Class B and C should each have their own implementation of `-(void)addNumbers;`

ClassC.m
-(void)addNumbers{
 c = a+b;
}

ClassB.m
-(void)addNumbers{
 c = a+b+d+1;
}

Comment: Can I ask for some clarification on the reasoning behind this. It may be worth implementing blocks in your case. As having a Protocol that has the need to call two simultaneous implementations seems strange.

Comment: @Unheilig I have some Java knowledge. I m still pretty new to programming in general

Answer (score 0):

Check the class of the delegate.

```
[[delegate class] isKindOfClass:[B class]]
```